# image editing function

Tags: php, function, image-manipulation

I've created a function to overlay text onto images, but I'm scratching my head to find a way of outputting the image in a way in which it can be utilised within another script or outputted to the screen.

I can call this function from a php script, passing it the image and the text to use, but when the function returns the data - it takes over the page due to the header - all I get as output is the image.

I suspect this is an easy one and just shows a hole in my PHP knowledge - can someone set me straight here?

Thanks!

function makeimage($file, $text) {
    ob_start();
        $x = getimagesize($file);
        $width = $x[0];
        $height = $x[1];
        $type = $x[2];

```
    //header('Content-type: $type');

    if ($type == 1) {
        $im = imagecreatefromgif($file);
    } elseif ($type==2) {
        $im = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
    } elseif ($type==3) {
        $im = imagecreatefrompng($file);
    }

    // Create some colors
    $white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
    $grey = imagecolorallocate($im, 128, 128, 128);
    $black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);

    // Replace path by your own font path
    $font = 'arial.ttf';

    // Add some shadow to the text
    imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 11, 21, $grey, $font, $text);

    // Add the text
    imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 10, 20, $black, $font, $text);

ob_clean(); //to be sure there are no other strings in the output buffer
imagepng($im);
$string = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
return $string;
```

}

I want to create this image, and then have it outputted in such a way as I can display it on screen in amongst all the other output.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "inserted back into a string", which part do you want returned as a string and for what purpose?

Comment: Hiya, sorry - i've edited and clarified :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put the script that output the image in a page, and call that page in a html  tag to display it.

Example:
image.php

```
<php
$image = $_GET['image'];
$text = $_GET['text'];
makeimage($image, $text);
?>
```

page.html:

```
<html>
<body>
<img src="image.php?image=foo.jpg&text=hello" />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to output the image directly, just don't send the header in your function. Every browser will treat the response as image file.

Also, imagedestroy($im) after return will never get executed!

If you want to just create the image and save it to a file, check the [imagepng() documentation](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.imagepng.php). The second parameter accepts a filename:

> The path to save the file to. If not
>   set or NULL, the raw image stream will
>   be outputted directly.

**According to your edit:**

You should use imagepng with the filename parameter to create the image, and then link to it from your script.

Small example:

```
<?php
// ...
imagepng($im, 'foo.png');
?>
<img src="foo.png" />
```

The other way around would be Davide Gualanos solution by using a wrapper script to passtrough image/png headers and direct output.

Answer (score 1):

you can use a temporary output buffer to catch the output of the function and then having a string filled with it

Example:

ob_start();

... your image function code ...

ob_clean(); //to be sure there are no other strings in the output buffer

imagepng($im);

$string = ob_get_contents();

ob_end_clean();

return $string;

$string got all the output from imagepng();

Comment: Hiya - I've used this, but it still returns base64 (or something) - a heap of code rather than an image, in other words. At least it's in the right place though!

Comment: have you tried to $string = base64_decode($string) to see if you've got the original image?